# Include local variables in an externally loaded string

Tags: python

For my application i like to store all messages in a seperate file and on function call insert local variables.

*messages.py*

`welcomemsg = 'hi {user} welcome to {service}'`

*functions.py*

```
import messages

def sayhi()
    user = 'John'
    service = 'Service name'
    print(f'{messages.welcomemsg}')
```

How to make the function output the string including the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a string containing format variables by itself, you will have to call the format method on it:

```py
messages.welcomemsg.format(user=user, service=service)
```

If you want to automatically format it using local variables you could use:

```py
messages.welcomemsg.format(**locals())
```

Answer (score 1):

Are String templates that you are after? You can have the string templates stored in another file but you will still need the additional work of doing calling the substitute method.

```
    from string import Template
    
    messagetemplate = Template("$user owns a $model")
    model = "Kwid" 
    user = "Dheeraj"
    variables = {
            "user": user,
            "model": model
        }
    print(messagetemplate.substitute(variables))
```

Comment: Actually previous comment was exactly what i was looking for but thanks for an alternative solution Dheeraj.